# Copy a part of a file to another file

Tags: java

I need to copy a part of one file to another file.
I know where the part starts and where it ends.
Of course I can loop the original file and start inserting the portion of the file I want, into the other file. The problem is, between the start and end there are app. 15 million lines.
So I am looking for a fast way without looping. Is there a way to find the start-tag ($START) and find the end-tag ($END) and then copy everything in between in a fast way?

My file looks like this:

```
#some comments
text
text
#interesing part start here
$START
1,tt
2,ff
.
.
$END
#some comments
```

Comment: Any attempts from your side ?

Comment: i don't think there is a way that allows you to do that

Comment: @SURESH ATTA: Yes, I tried with a loop of the file and then copy the interresting part into another. But with 15 mil+ lines, this took very long time. This is why I try my luck in here, to see, if anyone has a better idea.

Comment: Do you have all the file content in memory? In a String or so..

Comment: @EvertonAgner: My first attempt was reading from a randomaccess file by using .readLine().

Comment: @EvertonAgner 15 million lines bro, nobody wants to read the whole thing as once

Comment: You need to loop at least one time for finding out the start-tag ($START) and the end-tag ($END). So i don't think there is any way without looping.

Comment: Whoops, I've skipped that part on the question.

Answer (score 0):

There is only a

```
new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
    new FileInputStream(file), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1),
    1024L * 1024L);
```

With the tweak giving a larget buffer size.

Alternatively you could do a [MappedByteBuffer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/MappedByteBuffer.html), which should be a bit faster.
However then you need to write the string search yourself.

Count time needed for programming too.